# Create XML task file with installation path before running schtask.exe in Inno Setup

Tags: xml, inno-setup, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying create Inno Setup with scheduled task from XML file. The scheduled task is: My Application need to start with user login.

in Inno Setup script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; 
    \Parameters: "/create /XML ""{app}\Schedule.xml"" /TN AppStart"
```

in `Schedule.xml` file:

```xml
<Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
        <Command>"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
</Actions>
```

This works correctly. But I'd like to set the application path in XML file as `{app}\MyApp.exe`, because user can install it any location. How can I change this path in the XML file in the setup's run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/TR` switch, instead of using the XML to specify the path to run.

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Create /TR ""{app}\MyApp.exe"" /TN AppStart"
```

---

If you insist on using XML for some reason, you have to create the file on the fly.

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Create /XML ""{tmp}\Schedule.xml"""; \
    BeforeInstall: CreateScheduleXML
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CreateScheduleXML;
var
  FileName: string;
  AppPath: string;
begin
  FileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Schedule.xml');
  AppPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\MyApp.exe');
  { Create file here }
end;
```

You can create the file using simple functions like the [`SaveStringsToUTF8File`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_savestringstoutf8file) or use the `MSXML2.DOMDocument` COM object (see [Edit installed XML file according to user preferences in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39467048/850848)).