# With Innosetup, how to modify a key in a .net .exe.config file?

Tags: xml, config, inno-setup

with Innosetup, during the installation, the user can select some information (Port, Traces Level) using TInputQueryWizardPage and the path where to install the application (using TInputDirWizardPage)

Once all the files installed, I need to modify a file installed in {code:GetDataDir}

In NextButtonClick function, I added this code:

```
xmlPathFile := ExpandConstant('{code:GetDataDir}') + '\PL8_COMSRV\SampleServerExe.exe.config'; 
       UpdateConfigKeyValue(xmlPathFile,'//configuration/appSettings/add','PortSender',Level2PortPage.Values[0]);   
     UpdateConfigKeyValue(xmlPathFile,'//configuration/appSettings/add','PortReceiver',Level2PortPage.Values[1]);
```

The UpdateConfigKeyValue procedure is coming from an Innosetup example:
[how to modify the exe.config from Innosetup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602070/how-to-modify-the-exe-config-from-innosetup-script)

Unfortunately, when this function is called, the file is not yet installed.

My question, when can I call this procedure in order to modify an installed file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See [Edit installed file according to user preferences in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39467048/850848).

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution:
in [Files] Section:

```
Source: "\SampleServerExe.exe.config"; DestDir: "{code:GetDataDir}\PL8_COMSRV"; AfterInstall: UpdateConfigKeyValue(ExpandConstant('{code:GetDataDir}\PL8_COMSRV\SampleServerExe.exe.config'), '//configuration/appSettings/add','PortReceiver',ExpandConstant('{code:GetLevel2Param|PortEntree}'));
```