# How to read and write XML document node values in Inno Setup?

Tags: xml, inno-setup

I want to read some nodes of a XML file and show their values in some custom input fields. User can then change the values if needed, and by clicking the `Next` button these values should be saved back to the XML.

How to do this in Inno Setup script ?

Comment: Related question: [Inno Setup modify XML file based on custom input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8141886/588306).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the [`CreateOleObject`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoleobject) function to instantiate the standard [`MSXML2.DOMDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756987(v=vs.85)) COM object. The following script shows how to load and save a text value for a single node from the XML file posted below (the script itself was inspired by the examples from MSDN):

```pascal
[Code]
var
  CustomEdit: TEdit;
  CustomPageID: Integer;

function LoadValueFromXML(const AFileName, APath: string): string;
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  Result := '';
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      Result := XMLNode.text;
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

procedure SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.text := AValue;
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom Page', 
    'Enter the new value that will be saved into the XML file');
  CustomPageID := CustomPage.ID;
  CustomEdit := TEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  CustomEdit.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = CustomPageID then
    CustomEdit.Text := LoadValueFromXML('C:\Setup.xml', '//Setup/FirstNode');
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = CustomPageID then
    SaveValueToXML('C:\Setup.xml', '//Setup/FirstNode', CustomEdit.Text);
end;
```

Here is the XML file used in the script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Setup>
    <FirstNode>First node value!</FirstNode>
    <SecondNode>Second node value!</SecondNode>
</Setup>
```

Comment: P.S. it would be good to wrap each OLE object function call in this script with the [`OleCheck`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_olecheck.htm) which will raise the exception (earlier) when the function call fails (when the result will be different from the `S_OK` value).

Comment: The sample code may fail on Windows XP where MSXML 6.0 isn't available. Instead you should use version 3.0:

[...]
CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0');

Comment: @Daniel, good point! However, just `Msxml2.DOMDocument` should be enough (system should decide the version to use).

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Should it be updated to cater for silent installs and logging? Which is the right place in the script to edit the file after install?