# Execute a perl script with command line argument in inno setup run setup

Tags: inno-setup

In our application we need to change the property of the `jboss standalone-full.xml` file during installation. 
For that i have written a perl script which will accept xml file and value need to be modified as command line argument. I want to run this script during installation.
I have added below line in `{Run]` section of `.iss(inno setup)` file.

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; WorkingDir: "{app}\Perl64\"; Parameters: "/c ""bin\perl {app}\bin\makeHttpDisableScript.pl -file=""{app}\jboss\standalone\configuration\standalone-full.xml"" -httpEnabled=""false"""; StatusMsg: "Running perl script..."; Flags: runhidden
```

But it is not working.

Comment: That's a bit overkill, but well, doesn't the perl binary need quoted file name as well ? I mean this part `{app}\bin\makeHttpDisableScript.pl` you have unquoted...

Comment: Using Perl may be useless as you can modify XML file directly in Inno Setup using OLE object - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250266/how-to-read-and-write-xml-document-node-values

Comment: Thanks for the help. But xml file be there in the location only during installation.

Comment: You are executing your Perl script from the `[Run]` section, which is processed after the installation succeed. There is an event from which you can modify that file with the MSXML COM object and leave the Perl script way. Btw. how about that unquoted `{app}\bin\makeHttpDisableScript.pl` part ?

Comment: Hi TLama, your suggestion works. If i put quotes {app}\bin\makeHttpDisableScript.pl, it is working. Thanks a lot.Could you please tell me the event which can be used in msxml com object.

Comment: Sorry, I was not notified about your comment (you need to use `@` char before the user name, like e.g. `@TLama` to notify the user; we don't have to, since you are the post owner and as such you'll be always notified). Well, glad to hear that. About the MSXML way, I've found a way to define namespace prefixes thanks to [`this article`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313372/en-us).