# How to get node values from xml file and populate it using innosetup?

Tags: xml, inno-setup

I'm trying to read values from demo.xml file using innosetup and want to populate some sting values.Here is my demo.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<context>
<object name="sapconfig" class="com.iqc.egl.common.content.sap.SapConfig">
    <string value=""/>
    <string value="saplabs;usa"/>
    <string value="uae"/>
    <string value="002"/>   
</object>
```

Here i want output populated as: saplabs;usa and uae  .Can anybody guide me.Your help will be appreciated.This xml is static.

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between those attributes. All of them are `value` attributes of the `<string>` tag. The only way to extract only those inner two is picking them by index. But once the XML changes and those nodes gets shuffled, you'll get different values. Are you sure this is what you want ?

Comment: @TLama,This xml will remains same.

Comment: @TLama,can you tell me How to read values based on index.

Comment: This [something like this](http://pastebin.com/603b9dFR).

Comment: @TLama,Thanks a lot.Your link is awesome.Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of `Msxml2.DOMDocument` to access the xml file like explained here [How to read and write XML document node values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250266/how-to-read-and-write-xml-document-node-values)

You can iterate over the childnodes using `get_childNodes` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd873811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use `get_attribute` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd873626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx') to read "value".

Comment: Wosi,I'm unable to understand those links due to those example are in c++

Comment: Here are some snippets about how to do work with MSXML using Delphi: http://www.gerixsoft.com/blog/delphi/msxml
In Pascal Script it looks almost the same except that you are using `Variant` instead of `IXMLDOMNode` and `IXMLDOMNodeList`.

Comment: Wosi,is innosetup and Delphi both same?

Comment: OKie,i will try,can i use variant instead of IXMLDOMNODe,IXMLDOMNodeList?.

Comment: Yes, you can. `Variant` is a datatype for general purpose. It's made for _everything_: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Variant