# How to update multiple XML nodes in a loop with Inno Setup?

Tags: xml, inno-setup

I have to update a XML node that appears more than once, using Inno Setup.

How to do so?

For instance: I have to update `<details>` nodes (while I don't know how many nodes there are)

```
<server name="A">
    <details>id=5 gid=10</details>
</server>

<server name="B">
    <details>id=5 gid=10</details>
</server>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is modified version of code by @TLama from an answer to [How to read and write XML document node values in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11250266/850848#11254218)

In addition to his code, this version can update multiple nodes matching the XPath. The only difference is the call to `selectNodes` instead of `selectSingleNode` and the following `for` loop.

```pascal
procedure SaveValueToXMLNodes(const AFileName, APath, AValue: string);
var
  XMLDocument: Variant;
  XMLNodeList: Variant;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    begin
      MsgBox(
        'The XML file could not be parsed. ' + XMLDocument.parseError.reason,
         mbError, MB_OK)
    end
      else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNodeList := XMLDocument.selectNodes(APath);
      for Index := 0 to XMLNodeList.length - 1 do
      begin
        XMLNodeList.item[Index].text := AValue;
      end;
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occurred!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

For an input file like:

```xml
<root>
    <server name="A">
        <details>id=5 gid=10</details>
    </server>
    <server name="B">
        <details>id=5 gid=10</details>
    </server>
</root>
```

you can use the code like:

```pascal
SaveValueToXMLNodes('servers.xml', '/root/server/details', 'id=6 gid=11');
```

to get:

```xml
<root>
    <server name="A">
        <details>id=6 gid=11</details>
    </server>
    <server name="B">
        <details>id=6 gid=11</details>
    </server>
</root>
```