# How to read multiple XML nodes? (Inno Setup)

Tags: xml, inno-setup, pascalscript

This is the XML that I want to read. I have nodes with the same name. I want to access the nodes to show countries on a combo box and currencies on a list box.

This how XML looks like:

```
<listaPaises>
  <item>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>MÉXICO</name>
     <suggestedCurrency>PESO MEXICANO</suggestedCurrency>
  </item>
  <item>
     <id>4</id>
     <name>ARGENTINA</name>
     <suggestedCurrency>PESO ARGENTINO</suggestedCurrency>
  </item>
  <item>
     <id>23</id>
     <name>BELICE</name>
     <suggestedCurrency>DÓLAR BELICEÑO</suggestedCurrency>
  </item>
  <item>
     <id>5</id>
     <name>BOLIVIA</name>
     <suggestedCurrency>BOLIVIANO</suggestedCurrency>
  </item>
</listaPaises>
```

This is what I want: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard [`MSXML2.DOMDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756987(v=vs.85)) COM object and its [`SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754523(v=vs.85)) method.

```pascal
function LoadValuesFromXML(FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLNodeList: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
  Index: Integer;
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(FileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
    begin
      Log('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + XMLDocument.parseError.reason);
      Result := False;
    end
      else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNodeList := XMLDocument.SelectNodes('/listaPaises/item');
      for Index := 0 to XMLNodeList.length - 1 do
      begin
        XMLNode := XMLNodeList.item[Index];
        Log(
          Format('Name = %s; Currency = %s', [
            XMLNode.SelectSingleNode('name').Text,
            XMLNode.SelectSingleNode('suggestedCurrency').Text])); 
      end;
      Result := True;
    end;
  except
    Log('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

With your XML file, it will log:

```
Name = MÉXICO; Currency = PESO MEXICANO       
Name = ARGENTINA; Currency = PESO ARGENTINO   
Name = BELICE; Currency = DÓLAR BELICEÑO      
Name = BOLIVIA; Currency = BOLIVIANO
```

Just use that information to populate your combo box and list box (what is a separate question, if you do not know how).

---

The above is based on [How to update multiple XML nodes in a loop with Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34889265/850848)