# Error when passing from List Box to List Box in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Im trying to add items left from a ListBox1 to ListBox2 preventing duplicate,I got the code from my question [Prevent duplicate items in list box and combo box in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984621/prevent-duplicate-items-in-list-box-and-combo-box-in-inno-setup) (works perfect passing one by one) and i whant to pass all items at this time pressing button ">>" (pass items left on ListBox1 to ListBox2 (no clone list box)).
[image]

and get this on buttonClick
[image]

here's the code:

```
procedure botonDerechaTodos(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (listBoxMonedasDisponibles.ItemIndex >= 0)then
    begin
      if listBoxMonedasSecundarias.Items.IndexOf(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items[listBoxMonedasDisponibles.ItemIndex]) < 0 then 
         listBoxMonedasSecundarias.Items.Add(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items[listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items]);
         listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items.Delete(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items);       
         comboBoxMonedaPrincipal.Items := listBoxMonedasSecundarias.Items;
         comboBoxMonedaPrincipal.ItemIndex := 0;
         listBoxMonedasSecundarias.ItemIndex := 0;               
    end;  
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains an error. You're passing `Items` instead of `ItemIndex`.

You have

```
listBoxMonedasSecundarias.Items.Add(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items[listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items]);
```

It should be

```
listBoxMonedasSecundarias.Items.Add(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items[listBoxMonedasDisponibles.ItemIndex]);
```

You have a similar error here:

```
listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items.Delete(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items);
```

It should be

```
listBoxMonedasDisponibles.Items.Delete(listBoxMonedasDisponibles.ItemIndex);
```

In response to the question asked in your comment, use AddStrings (I'm not typing all of those long variable names):

```
ListBoxDest.Items.AddStrings(ListBoxSource.Items);
ListBoxSource.Items.Clear;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for what I want,
I already use that code you say without problem to button ">" (passing item  one by one), but  i want to add(pass) all items left from listBoxMonedasDisponibles to listBoxMonedasSecundarias to make button ">>"(Passing all). is there any way to modify to do that?

Comment: Thank you so much, I really apreciated.