# How to read tag attribute of XML in Inno Setup

Tags: xml, xpath, inno-setup, pascalscript

Here is the XML file :

```xml
<book_info>
    <book title = "Peter Pan">
        <publisher name="Penguin" edition="2nd" date ="2/6/2016" />
        <Page size= "207" />
        <author name = "J M Barrie"/>
        <info genre  = "novel" lang = "English"/>
    </book>
    <book title = "Room of Many Color">
        <publisher name="Penguin" edition="1st" date ="3/11/2000" />
        <Page size= "387" />
        <author name = "Ruskin Bond"/>
        <info genre  = "sort stories" lang = "English"/>
    </book>
</book_info>
```

Here is how I am trying to access the publisher name :

```pascal
bookXML := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
bookXML.async := False;
bookXML.load(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\book.xml'));
bookNode := bookXML.SelectSingleNode('//book_info/book[name/text()=' + bookName + ']');
bookPubName := bookNode.SelectSingleNode('publisher[name]').text;
```

But it is always giving NIL interface exception for the last line.

```pascal
bookPubName := bookNode.SelectSingleNode('publisher[name]').text;
```

I checked [How to select XML tag based on value of its child tag in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336112/how-to-select-xml-tag-based-on-value-of-its-child-tag-in-inno-setup) but could not resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to do. Your XPath for `bookNode` refers to a `name` tag, but a `book` has no `name` tag, not even an `name` attribute.

---

Anyway, let's assume that you want to find out a value of `name` attribute of `publisher` tag of a `book` with `title` (?) attribute equal to a given value.

- Refer to `title` attribute using `@title` instead of referring to a text content of a non-existing `name` tag:

  ```
  //book_info/book[@name=...]
  ```
- Wrap the string value to single-quotes (you have to double them in Pascal string):

  ```pascal
  '//book_info/book[@name=''' + bookName + ''']'
  ```
- To select a value of `name` attribute of `publisher` tag, again use `@name` syntax (`name` refers to a non-existing sub-tag).

  ```
  publisher[@name]
  ```

---

And you can merge both XPaths into one like:

```pascal
bookPubName :=
    bookXML.SelectSingleNode(
        '//book_info/book[@title=''' + bookName + ''']/publisher/@name').text;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Prikryl. My original xml is different so forgot to replace name with title. But it is really that single quotes which was the issue. It is working now.