# Computing a value of command parameter in Inno Setup Icons section

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

My question is the the continuation of [Inno Setup - "Variant is null, cannot invoke" error while reading node value in XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937780/inno-setup-variant-is-null-cannot-invoke-error-while-reading-node-value-in). In this post, I am reading an XML file node and successfully able to take the value using the procedure `ProcGetWebAppNameFromXML` and I am trying to pass the value to the `[Icons]` section, but I am getting empty.

The code snippet is mentioned below.

```
[Run]

Filename: "{app}\test1.bat"; StatusMsg: "Running Services..."; \
    BeforeInstall: ProcGetWebAppNameFromXML;

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\App"; Filename: "{pf}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";  \
    Parameters: """http://{code:GetWebAppNameFromXML|}/"""
```

The procedure `ProcGetWebAppNameFromXML` gets the webapp name (works completely fine) and I am assigning it to a global variable.

```pascal
[Code]
var
    WebAppNameFromXML: String;

procedure ProcGetWebAppNameFromXML();
var
    ...
    ...
    WebAppNameFromXML := LoadValueFromXML(applicationxmlFile, '//ns:application-name', 'application-name');
    Log('WebApp name is logged correctly here..' + WebAppNameFromXML);
end;
```

I am using the below mentioned function to assign the value.

```
function GetWebAppNameFromXML(Default: String): String;
begin
    Result := WebAppNameFromXML;
end;
```

When I pass the function `GetWebAppNameFromXML` to the `Icons` section I am getting empty. Please note that I have `[Icons]` below the `[Run]` section and I have used `ChangesAssociations=yes` too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Run]` section is processed as the last one. So after `[Icons]` section.
See https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder

And it looks like you are actually abusing it anyway.

Call `ProcGetWebAppNameFromXML` in [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

Or if you need `WebAppNameFromXML` for your `[Icons]` section only, read the XML directly in `GetWebAppNameFromXML` – And you won't need any global variables.