# Read XML attribute value in Inno Setup

Tags: xml, inno-setup, msxml2

Using [How to read and write XML document node values in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250266/how-to-read-and-write-xml-document-node-values-in-inno-setup) I'm able to read values from XML file.

My file is not type XML but config (myApp.exe.config) with XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="foo" type="bar">
      <section name="foo2" type="bar2" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="foo3" type="bar3" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="foo, bar">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="AppEntities" connectionString="NEED THIS VALUE" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>  
</configuration>
```

When using:

```pascal
LoadValueFromXML(
  ExpandConstant('{app}\myApp.exe.config'),
  '//configuration/connectionStrings/add');
```

or

```pascal
LoadValueFromXML(
  ExpandConstant('{app}\myApp.exe.config'),
  '//configuration/connectionStrings');
```

I'm still getting empty string.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

See [Extract value of attribute node via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4835891/850848).

So in your case, the XPath is:

```xml
/configuration/connectionStrings/add/@connectionString
```

(also note the single leading `/` - as `<configuration>` is the root tag)

Comment: Learning every day, many thanks.